# Decreasing Sequences compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This question will seem very trial for a lot of you but for some reasons I can't get it to work properly.

In a Metric Space $(X,\rho)$, we have a decreasing sequence of compact sets $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \dots \supset A_n \supset A_{n+1} \supset \dots$

a) Prove that $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is a nonempty compact set.

b) Prove that
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \eta \in \mathbb{N}: \; \forall n \geq \eta \: B(A,\epsilon) \supset A_n
$$
*Hint*: Do it by contradiction

I was able to do a) without too much problem but somehow stuck at b) while it doesn't look too complicated. I think that the contrapositive of the statement is

$$
\exists \epsilon > 0 \: \forall \eta \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq \eta \; B(A,\epsilon ) \subset A_n 
$$

Comment: The inclusion is opposite: $A_n \supseteq A$.

Comment: Oh wow nevermind. Big mistake on my part I was treating $A$ as if it was $A_1$

Comment: You need to assume that each of the $A_n$ is nonempty.

Comment: I proved that for a), how do I use it for b)?

Comment: It is an assumption, not something you can prove.

Comment: For b), note that $A_1 \setminus B(A,\epsilon)$ is a compact set.

Comment: Right, I've proved that A was nonempty, but to do that I had to assume $A_n$ were not empty indeed.

Comment: Note that $A_n \setminus B(A,\epsilon)$ is a nested sequence of compact sets. If they were all non empty then you could get a quick contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A_n'=A_n\setminus B(A,\epsilon) \subset A_n$ is a nested sequence of compact sets.

Note that $A \cap A_n' =\emptyset$ for all $n$.

By a), if $A_n'$ is non empty for all $n$ then $A' = \cap _n A_n' \subset \cap_n A_n = A$ is non empty, however $A' \cap A = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Hence $A_N'$ is empty for some $N$ (and hence all $n \ge N$, since the sets are nested). It follows that $A_n \subset B(A,\epsilon)$ for all $n \ge N$.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive is

\begin{equation} \exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \eta \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq \eta B(A, \epsilon) \not\supset A_n\end{equation}

Now let $\eta = 1$ we can find $n_1\geq 1$ such that $\exists x_{n_1} \in A_{n_1}$ with $x_{n_1} \not\in B(A, \epsilon)$. By induction, we can find $n_{k} > n_{k-1}$ such that $\exists x_{n_k} \in A_{n_k}$ with $x_{n_k} \not\in B(A, \epsilon)$. Now the sequence $(x_{n_k})$ have the following property:

\begin{equation} \forall k \in \mathbb{N} x_{n_k} \not\in B(A,\epsilon).\end{equation}

But $(x_{n_k})$ is a sequence in a compact set thus there exist a subsequence $(x_{n_{k^{'}}})$ which is convergent. It's limit, which we shall call it $x$, must be in $A$. Cause for every $n$ the subsequence of $(x_{n_{k^{'}}})$ with $n_{k^{'}} > n$ is in $A_n$ a compact set and thus $x \in A_n$. Since $x_{n_{k^{'}}} \rightarrow x \in A$ we have the following property:

\begin{equation} \exists N: \forall n_{k^{'}}>N x_{n_{k^{'}}} \in B(x,\epsilon) \subset B(A,x).\end{equation}

Which is a contradiction.